# What is the easy way to edit the maintenance / error 503 page?

Tags: magento2

I'd like to modify the generic blank page with a custom template

> Service Temporarily Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create/edit the errors/local.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <skin>customtheme</skin>
</config>
```

Then create a copy of errors/default folder and call it customtheme.

From this point, you can edit the phtml files as well as add the css files to create your own custom theme.

EDIT: even though it has been approved as a valid answer, this answer is only relevant for Magento 1 and I did not see it was a Magento 2 question.

Thus, the right way of designing the maintenance page is by editing the pub/errors/default/503.phtml page.

Comment: Is it the local.xml under <m2root>/pub/errors?

Comment: If your Magento install is under /pub I guess so. Find out where your app folder is, the errors folder should be on the same level.

Comment: Inside my Magento install are: app, bin, dev, lib, phpserver, pub, setup, update, var, vendor.
Inside app are: code, design, etc, i18n.
But no errors folder :/

Comment: Interesting, and how does your 503 page looks like right now ? Does it look like the Magento default theme or totally white ?

Comment: It looks totally white

Comment: Yes so I guess the errors folder was never there in the first place, download a default errors folder by downloading the Magento archive, add this folder to your magento install repo then follow my instructions to create your custom error page theme.

Comment: doesn't seem to work, but following your instructions with the errors folder inside the pub folder works. Just not sure if it's the good way to do it but I take it for now, thanks :)

Answer (score 24):

Actually, you don't need to edit core files for this purpose. Just copy `pub/errors/local.xml.sample` to `pub/errors/local.xml`, then make a copy of `pub/errors/default` (let's say `pub/errors/custom`). Change the `skin` value of the `pub/errors/local.xml` to the newly created errors skin:

```
<config>
    <skin>custom</skin>
    ....
```

After this you are able to make changes in `pub/errors/custom/503.phtml` and other files.

Comment: Yup, this one is the correct answer for M2.

Comment: Great idea, but this is broken in the 2.1.* branch. There's a fix that should be released in 2.2 So if you are using 2.1 then... sorry, no custom skin for you - see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4305

Comment: I can confirm @yaroslav-rogoza solution is working in 2.1.4 Enterprise.