# Can we change default error pages of Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, error

I want to know that can we change default error pages of magento without touching core files of magento 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The similar question has been already discussed and answered here.
[What is the easy way to edit the maintenance / error 503 page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97000/what-is-the-easy-way-to-edit-the-maintenance-error-503-page)
The described principle works for all error pages.