# How to Override pub/errors/default/503.phtml

Tags: magento2, error

Hello How to Override pub/errors/default/503.phtml into my custom module Magento Version 2.1.10

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/125898/48571

Comment: Hello @Magento2Learner this is used for only 404 CMS Page . You Can Provide 503.phtml apply code ?

Comment: Hello @DineshYadav This is not For Our Module and into 503.phtml we are not able to call static block , layout etc