# Override magento2/pub/errors/default/503.phtml using custom module

Tags: magento2

How to Override below phtml file in magento 2 **using custom module**?

`magento2/pub/errors/default/503.phtml`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easy way to edit the maintenance / error 503 page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97000/what-is-the-easy-way-to-edit-the-maintenance-error-503-page)

Comment: thanks, but I need it using custom module