# How to redirect to custom/website maintenance page when hit an error?

Tags: magento-2.1, frontend-error, maintenance, theme-overriding

How to make the redirection to `custom page` or other `website's Maintenance Page` when my **Magento** reports an error? Instead of showing the debug page no matter in which mode my website is.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97000/what-is-the-easy-way-to-edit-the-maintenance-error-503-page

Comment: Is there anyway beside code level change?

Comment: unfortunatly there is no other way to do this.